# Creating dynamic dropdown list in AngularJS from two or more sources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a nested object like this:

```
ObjectA-ObjectB-AddressObject-address1
ObjectA-ObjectB-ObjectC-AddressObject-address2
```

I would like to create dropdown list to a form so that there is always ObjectC's address as a default if there is one. I am totally newbie in AngularJS, so what is the correct way to that? Should I create some kind of option list in my controller or is there any more correct way to that? I tried to search answers to that from Stack, but there is plenty of different solutions. I think that I can't use ngOptions because options are coming from two different source, correct?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="rma.customerCustomerId.addressAddressId.address"  placeholder="Address"> 

<input type="text" ng-model="rma.retailerRetailerId.addressAddressId.address" placeholder="Address">
```

I just tried to get values in my controller:

```
console.log(rma.customerCustomerId.addressAddressId.address);
console.log(rma.retailerRetailerId.addressAddressId.address);
```

[image]

Comment: so you have an array of such nested objects, some of which have `ObjectC`?

Comment: You should create one option list from nested objects by iterating over address objects. And then display that option list in ng-option of select tag.

Comment: It's not clear where the possible addresses you could choose are coming from or when.

Comment: @Replictus - No I just have ObjectA which includes B and  ObjectB includes in some cases ObjectC. There is only two addresses, there is addressObject inside of Object B and ObjectC, no arrays at all.

Comment: Tony H - The addresses are coming from the same form. There is two different address fields, address1 and address2. I need to create dynamically dropdown where is only those two addresses so that address two is as a default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with one of the comment in the question.  This doesn't feel like angular problem.  You should just transform your domain model into a more appropriate view model.  In the simplest example, probably something like this.

If your model looks like this:

```
    self.foo = {
        bar : {
            addr : { value : 'Bar.Address' },
            baz : {
                addr : { value : 'Baz.Address' }
            }
        }
    };
```

Then, you can flatten this using something like:

```
       var result = [];
        if (self.foo.bar.baz) result.push(self.foo.bar.baz.addr.value);
        result.push(self.foo.bar.addr.value);

        self.addresses = result;
```

And then just bind the selected address to the first element in the resulting array:

```
self.selectedAddress = self.addresses[0];
```

Putting it together, you get something like the snippet below.

```js
(function(undefined) {
    'use strict';
    
    angular.module('myApp',[]);
    
    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
    
    myCtrl.$inject = ['$log', '$scope'];
    function myCtrl($log, $scope) {
        var self = this;
        
        self.foo = {
            bar : {
                addr : { value : 'Bar.Address' },       //remove baz element below to simulate that it's not there.
                baz : {
                    addr : { value : 'Baz.Address' }    //This will be preferred if exists...
                }
            }
        };
        
        self.selectedAddress = undefined;
        self.addresses = [];
      
        $scope.$watch(function() { return self.foo.bar.baz.addr.value; }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
          bindAddresses();
        });

        activate();

        function activate() {
            bindAddresses();
        }
        
        function bindAddresses() {
            var result = [];
            if (self.foo.bar.baz && self.foo.bar.baz.addr && self.foo.bar.baz.addr.value) {
              result.push(self.foo.bar.baz.addr.value);
            }
            result.push(self.foo.bar.addr.value);
            
            self.addresses = result;
            self.selectedAddress = self.addresses[0];
        }
    }
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <form ng-controller='myCtrl as vm'>
      
        <p>
        Address 1
        <input ng-model="vm.foo.bar.addr.value" />
        </p>
      
      
        <p>
        Address 2
        <input ng-model="vm.foo.bar.baz.addr.value" />
        </p>
      
      
        <select ng-model='vm.selectedAddress' ng-options='addr for addr in vm.addresses'></select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I update the dropdown immediately when user has inserted the addresses before submitting the form? Please watch the attached image.

Comment: You can add a $scope.$watch on the second address, either on a particular field or all of them I guess and if there is a value, call bindAddresses again in the callback function.

Comment: Updated the snippet to do the auto refresh.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I just didn't get it how you get values from input fields automatically to dropdown? I edited my question.

Comment: The $scope.$watch line is one part of it. When  self.foo.bar.baz.addr.value changes, it will call bindAddresses.  bindAddresses basically reflatten the model into the addresses array and it is also responsible to update the selectedAddress to the first thing in the addresses array (self.selectedAddresses = self.addresses[0]).